# Changing root password does not change sudo password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, sudo

I’m trying to change the password that is asked when running `sudo` in Ubuntu. Running `sudo passwd` or `sudo passwd root` does give me the two new password prompts and it successfully changes the password.

But then I can still use my old password when running `sudo` again for something else.  I do have a user with the exact same password but I don’t know if that makes a difference.  I enabled the root user and I can see the new password does work with the root user account.

So the root password is changed but not the password for `sudo`.

How do I change the `sudo` password?

Comment: root password is used by `su`, it is your password that is used by `sudo`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're changing root's password. `sudo` wants your user's password.

To change it, try plain `passwd`, without arguments or running it through `sudo`.

Alternately, you can issue:

```
$ sudo passwd <your username>
```

Comment: And learn more about `/etc/sudoers` which configure the behavior of `sudo`

Comment: You are right, I see it asks the user password, that was not so smart of me. So what I need to do is remove the user from the soduers/admin group.

Answer (score 9):

The password you use for sudo is the password of your own account, not the root account. `sudo` is used to grant you access to commands that need to be executed as root without giving you root access directly. To change your own password, use `passwd` without sudo.

Comment: thanks for responding, you were fast, but not fast enough for the point:), but thanks though